# jQuery tooltip hover loops animation

Tags: jquery, loops, hover, tooltip, eventtrigger

I created a custom tooltip system in jQuery that creates a new element with CSS styling to position it above all of the other items and in the proper location.

Everything works properly, but when the mouse moves over the tooltip, any animation that was caused by hovering over the parent object starts looping.

Is there some way that I could prevent the hover event from triggering on my tooltips?

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/UzUct/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Change this part of the Script:

```
// Parent Hover Script
$(".item").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": "0.5"
    },"fast");
},function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    },"fast");
});
```

You should give [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the previous animation! :)

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UzUct/4/

Comment: That works on my mini-example, but on my large-scale example (which uses the same basic code) sometimes I can't trigger the hover event more than once, and when the hover event on the thumbnail is triggered, it starts fading in and stops in the middle.

Comment: Can you show if it is publicly accessible (yeah, and no copyright violations, or privacy issues), so that I can test it out and let you know?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not publicly accessible at the moment (it's on my local machine) but I updated the jsfiddle with a better example.  It's not happening as much (for some reason) in the jsfiddle but I would like to get rid of the tooltip flickering and sometimes the hover items would fade out without the mouse moving out of the frame (due to hover over the tooltip)